# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error when using JSONDecoder

Tags: swift, codable, decodable, jsondecoder

I'm trying to decode a very simple json with Swift's JSONDecoder, by using `KeyDecodingStrategy.convertFromSnakeCase`. I get the following error and I don't understand why:

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
```

This is the console output I get:

```
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "latestBuildVersion", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"latestBuildVersion\", intValue: nil) (\"latestBuildVersion\"), converted to latest_build_version.", underlyingError: nil)): file MyPlayground.playground, line 14
```

When I don't use the keyDecodingStrategy and give an enum with the coding keys, everything works fine. Here's the playground code that causes the error:

```
import UIKit

struct App: Codable {
  var stacks: Set<Stack>
}

struct Stack : Codable, Hashable {
var latestBuildVersion: Int

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try! decoder.container(keyedBy: Stack.CodingKeys.self)


    latestBuildVersion = try! container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .latestBuildVersion)

  }
}
let jsonData = """
  {
    "stacks":
    [
        {
          "latest_build_version": 436346213
        }
    ]
  }
""".data(using: .utf8)!
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
jsonDecoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let stack = try! jsonDecoder.decode(Stack.self, from: jsonData)
print(stack.latestBuildVersion)
```

Comment: First of all use `guard let or if let`, you have added `try!` which means you are `forcefully` unwrapping an optional values and in this case it is failing and that is why it is throwing the error.

Comment: Same thing when decoding, don't do try! but use a do/catch instead. Also I think stacks needs to be declared as an array and not a set